# Javascript and canvas issues

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am having an issue with my javascript not doing anything when the page loads here is my html and my javascript I am stumped I have no clue what the issue is(sorry for the poor spacing i did this on my iphone)

index.php

```
    <canvas id="breakout" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

   <script>

    var canvas =  document.getElementById("breakout") ;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


    var x = canvas.width/2;
    var y = canvas.height-30;
    var mx = 2;
    var my = -2;

    function checkCollision{
    if(y + my < 0){
    my = -my;
    }
    if(y + my > canvas.height){
    my = -my;
    }
    if(x + mx > canvas.width-ballRadius){
    mx = -mx;
    }
    if(x + mx < ballRadius){
    mx = -mx;
    }
    }

    function drawBall{
     var ballRadius = 10;
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(x,y,ballRadius,0, Math.PI*2);
     ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
     ctx.fill();
     ctx.closePath();
    }

    function drawing{
     ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
     drawBall();
     x += mx;
     y += my;
     checkCollision();
      }

     setInterval(drawing,10);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not defining your functions properly. You need to define functions like so:

```
function foo() {
    ...
}
```

Doing:

```
function foo{
    ...
}
```

Is not valid and will lead to an error in the console. Also since `ballRadius` is being used in many functions, define it outside the function `drawBall`:

```
var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height-30;
var mx = 2;
var my = -2;
var ballRadius = 10; // Added
```

```js
var canvas =  document.getElementById("breakout") ;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height-30;
var mx = 2;
var my = -2;
var ballRadius = 10;

function checkCollision(){
    if(y + my < 0){
      my = -my;
    }
    if(y + my > canvas.height){
      my = -my;
    }
    if(x + mx > canvas.width-ballRadius){
      mx = -mx;
    }
    if(x + mx < ballRadius){
      mx = -mx;
    }
}

function drawBall(){
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(x,y,ballRadius,0, Math.PI*2);
     ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
     ctx.fill();
     ctx.closePath();
}

function drawing() {
     ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
     drawBall();
     x += mx;
     y += my;
     checkCollision();
}

     setInterval(drawing,10);
```

```html
<canvas id="breakout" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks ive been looking at it so long i looked over the most obvious thing

Comment: @JoséphFlames Using a linter like [jsHint](http://jshint.com/) or [jsLint](http://jslint.com/) can help find these kinds of syntax errors (and a number of other potential headaches) fast before they drive you crazy ;-)